# Package distribution

Tags: code-golf

While at work I spotted a nice and simple challenge.

The job was to stock products in cargo units with a certain capability.
Since an order can have various batches, coming in sequence from the production, we usually make a list of the pieces of those batches distributed in each cargo to make sure nothing is lost during the process.

For example if we had this production sheet:

```
 _____________
|ord: xxx     |
|_____________|
| A | 30 pcs  |
| B | 38 pcs  |
| C | 12 pcs  |
 —————————————
```

and our cargo could contain 12 pieces we would make this list:

```
A | 12 12  6-
B | -6 12 12  8-
C | -4  8//
```

where **x**`-` indicates that **x** pieces will be stocked with `-`**y** pieces of the next line and **z**`//` indicates that after those **z** pieces there's a different order, thus nothing more we can add, and the last cargo is complete.

## Task

In this challenge you have to take a production sheet and a cargo capacity and output the distributed list.

## Specifications

Production sheet is taken in the form of a sequence of numbers representing the batches amounts.

You have to output just the distributed amounts, we don't care about the additional signs `-` `//` mentioned above.

Every batch must be distributed separately, so the output is a list of lists which you can represent in any reasonable format, just specify it and be consistent.

It's guarantee that:

- each batch has at least one piece
- cargo units can contain at least one piece
- an order( input list ) has at least one batch

So you have to handle only positive integers( >0 ).

### input:

a list of numbers representing the production sheet and a number representing the cargo capacity, each positive integers, in any reasonable method / order.

### output:

the distributed list in form of a list of lists of numbers in any convenient method.

- No extraneous numbers can appear in the output.
- Order of obtained lists must be preserved.

## Test cases

```
 [30, 38, 12], 12 => [[12,12,6],[6,12,12,8],[4,8]]
 [1],1 => [[1]]
 [2],1 => [[1,1]]
 [1],2 => [[1]]
 [1,12,34],20 => [[1],[12],[7,20,7]]
 [5],1 => [[1,1,1,1,1]]
 [5],5 => [[5]]
 [300,120],84 => [[84,84,84,48],[36,84]]
 [1,2,3,4,5],6 => [[1],[2],[3],[4],[2,3]]
 [2,5,16,38,32,38,38,34,8,30,31,9,12],15 => [[2],[5],[8,8],[7,15,15,1],[14,15,3],[12,15,11],[4,15,15,4],[11,15,8],[7,1],[14,15,1],[14,15,2],[9],[4,8]]
```

## Rules

- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT, return it as a function result or error message/s.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

<sub>[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20702/84844)</sub>

Comment: I thought this was a question about implementing `dpkg` or something horrifying

Comment: @qwr I never heard of dpkg before, just opened wiki and got scared, this is just a simple counting problem we solve everyday at work by hand. I thought it was a simple and relaxing challenge but with so few answer it was probably more difficult to solve by code

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>36 34 27</sup> 24 bytes

```
(]<@(#/.~)/.[:I.#\&:-)I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3dCoJAEEbvfYohoRTGbX9tlYIoCIToolvTm0iim96gV7eZ1VrYGQ6H75t9jQuxGmBXwwoQJNQ0hYDj9Xwas267z9K1@ORr0daNSG/LusgbMeZJ8rg/36A0DGAkGE84KzIq4mx1tFoyc9XYmHMTuojehtuSknIyZShSD@wvpLig0aEq0Xg0Omx6FmlJNAorpK@Sy0FA30Pb6g5bR@PR096gcuERK8tkmHRwLO0csKwV01z7FyLx6Sp0fNeNXw)

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to Bubbler</sup>

Takes capacity as left arg and production sheet as right arg.

### how

Use `12 f 30 38 12` as an example.

- `(...)I.` A dyadic hook which expands the right arg into a mask with 30 `0`s, 38 `1`s, and 12 `2`s:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
  ```
- `#\&:-` makes both arguments negative `&:-`. The `_12` on the left means "chunks of size 12" and `#\` will count each:

  ```
   12 12 12 12 12 12 8
  ```
- `[:I.` Use the same expansion trick we used before to expand each of those in place into a unique integer:

  ```
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
  ```
- `].../.` Use the mask from step 1 to group the output of the last step into groups of size 30, 38, and 12:

  ```
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 
    2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
    5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
  ```
- `(#/.~)/.` For each of *those* groups, self-group by value, returning a list of the number of items in each group:

  ```
    _________ 12 ________   ________ 12 _________   ___ 6 ___ 
   /                     \ /                     \ /         \
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 

    ___ 6 ___   ________ 12 _________   ________ 12 _________   _____ 8 _____
   /         \ /                     \ /                     \ /             \
   2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

    _ 4 _   _____ 8 _____
   /     \ /             \
   5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
  ```
- Finally, box each of those results `<@` because J doesn't allow ragged arrays.

Comment: -1: `(<.@%~[:i.+/)` -> `I.@(#\&:-I.)`

Comment: Then factor out the monadic `I.` on the right arg to get [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY3dCoJAEEbvfYohoRTGbX9tlYIoCIToolvTm0iim96gV7eZ1VrYGQ6H75t9jQuxGmBXwwoQJNQ0hYDj9Xwas267z9K1@ORr0daNSG/LusgbMeZJ8rg/36A0DGAkGE84KzIq4mx1tFoyc9XYmHMTuojehtuSknIyZShSD@wvpLig0aEq0Xg0Omx6FmlJNAorpK@Sy0FA30Pb6g5bR@PR096gcuERK8tkmHRwLO0csKwV01z7FyLx6Sp0fNeNXw).

Comment: @Bubbler Those are some lovely insights.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÇÑ▄≥Ué(ΘⁿGD$▀X9♦;ûΘ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80a5dcf2558228e9fc474424df5839043b96e9&i=12+%5B30,+38,+12%5D%0A1+%5B1%5D%0A1+%5B2%5D%0A2+%5B1%5D%0A20+%5B1,12,34%5D%0A1+%5B5%5D%0A5+%5B5%5D%0A84+%5B300,120%5D%0A6+%5B1,2,3,4,5%5D%0A15+%5B2,5,16,38,32,38,38,34,8,30,31,9,12%5D&m=2)

#### Explanation:

Unpacked source:

```
{i]*m$s/{|Rm:f{h}/mMHJ
```

- Implicit input: 12 [30 38 12]
- `{i]*m`: Map over array:

  - `i]`: Push singleton array with index, e.g. [1]
  - `*`: Repeat by corresponding element, e.g. [1 1 1 1 1 ... (38 times)]
- Result: [[<30 times 0>] [<38 times 1>] [<12 times 2>]]
- `$`: Flatten: [<30 times 0> <38 times 1> <12 times 2>]
- `s/`: Split into groups of maximum package size: [[<12 times 0>] [<12 times 0>] [<6 times 0> <6 times 1>] [<12 times 1>] [<12 times 1>] [<8 times 1> <4 times 2>] [<8 times 2>]
- `{|Rm`: Run-length-encode each element: [[[0 12]] [[0 12]] [[0 6] [1 6]] [[1 12]] [[1 12]] [[1 8] [2 4]] [[2 8]]]
- `:f`: Flatten: [[0 12] [0 12] [0 6] [1 6] [1 12] [1 12] [1 8] [2 4] [2 8]]
- `{h}/`: Split into groups with equal first element: [[[0 12] [0 12] [0 6]] [[1 6] [1 12] [1 12] [1 8]] [[2 4] [2 8]]]
- `m`: For each element, e.g. [[0 12] [0 12] [0 6]]

  - `M`: Transpose: [[0 0 0] [12 12 6]]
  - `H`: Second element: [12 12 6]
  - `J`: Join with spaces: "12 12 6"
  - Implicit print

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

Expects `(capacity)(list)`.

```javascript
n=>a=>a.map(g=v=>v?[x=v>m?m:v,...g(v-x,m=m-x||n)]:[],m=n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFNa8MwDL3vV4SebFBcfyRuVnD6Q7wcQteGjtopbTE59L9nsrNB1@QwWwgJ3hPvSV9taG/76@lyz33/eRiPZvSmbjGYay@kM8HUYWcHE2q3c9sAjLGOhHwAZ1w@PB6eNlvbYOfpuO/9rT8f2LnvyJEISYlVHFQFQjaUZtl6nVkrJLagG7AaprrCusDcvL0MQL5IxN83DVgEygUgzKHyvzMlj8goTxUT/gcI6ADTBiSHzaKUclHK9GeEcplQzoBVkdbJURJ/ElTh5lIUcY1KYzmj6mQFnUAB5dMlkBCtqLj/WINC6h/u6sOv6KvFKFlCCULH2yqZMgbKgHhvAe/Txcdv)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => a =>              // n = cargo capacity, a[] = production list
  a.map(g = v =>       // for each quantity v in a[]:
    v ?                //   if v is not equal to 0:
      [                //     build a new array:
        x = v > m ? m  //       append x = min(m, v)
                  : v, //       
        ...g(          //       split the result of a recursive call:
          v - x,       //         subtract x from v
          m = m - x    //         subtract x from m; if the result is 0:
              || n     //           restart with a new cargo of capacity n
        )              //       end of recursive call
      ]                //     end of array
    :                  //   else:
      [],              //     stop the recursion
    m = n              //   start with m = n
  )                    // end of map()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping doing my job so fast!

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>[67](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/219398/1)</s> 66 bytes

*1 byte saved by xnor*

```haskell
f c|let(a:d)?b|a<=b=[a]:d?(b-a)|x:y<-(a-b:d)?c=(b:x):y;_?_=[]=(?c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxCoAwDADArzg4pGDB4hYNfUgpklRFsYqog0L/XhFuu5mvdYwx56kIKY43MA7KSuKOhBx7HCyIZpUefDsNrOX/QCD4KHzb3vbkPIENKm@87HScy36XU9E4U1c/4/MH)

I think this takes the cake as the most unreadable Haskell I have written.  We have a pattern guard inside a pattern guard which I am actually surprised Haskell can even parse.

Here it is ungolfed:

```haskell
f c
  | let
    (a:d)?b
      | a <= b
        = [a]:d?(b-a)
      | x:y <- (a-b:d)?c
        = (b:x):y
    _?_
     = []
  = (?c)
```

Comment: Wow! That's crazy! I don't understand how the second sub guard works `x:y <- c?(a-b:d) = ..`, there's no condition 0.o

Comment: @AZTECCO The condition there is a pattern match.  If `c?(a-b:d)` did not match `x:y` (that is it is an empty list) it would fail.  That being said more generally you can use pattern matches in guards even when they can't fail e.g. `x <- m+3` basically acts as an assignment.

Comment: ♦  thanks! Ok so it does two things simultaneously : check if a?b 
 produce a list(which is a guard) and assigns it to t x:y which is then used in the result if I understood, but where's the edge case ? Is it `_?_ `? But it's outside the guards.. Omg!

Comment: `_?_` is a catch all, it is performed if nothing else matches.  It's the base case it only ever gets called when the list is empty.

Comment: Can you swap the two sides of `?` to cut the space?

Comment: @xnor Yes?  Thank you? ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
OÝI÷¹£εÅγ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9vc2FiaWX//0/DnUnDt8K5wqPOtcOFzrP//1szMCwzOCwxMl0KMTI) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WmVBsr6SQmJeioGQPZDxqmwRkAAUPrfzvf3hu8eHth9YdWnxu6@HWc5v/1@r8j46ONjbQMbbQMTSKBWOF6GhDIAvMMIIxgCRUCqhGx9gEyDUA801hKoAMUzDD2MAAqAYoa2EC1QHUoGMCkjWDGKpjqmNoBrLS2AhMApGJDpAAOsNQxxLiENPYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
O          # Sum the first (implicit) input-list
 Ý         # Push a list in the range [0,sum]
  I÷       # Integer-divide each by the second input-integer
    ¹£     # Split it into groups of the first input-list amount of values
      ε    # Map over each group:
       Åγ  #  And run-length encode it, which will put the values and counts as two
           #  separated lists to the stack, and since we're using a large map `ε`, it
           #  will only leave the top one with the counts
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
ＵＭθ…Ｅι⊞Ｏυκ⁰Ｆ⪪υηＦ…·⌊ι⌈ι⊞§θκ№ικＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsIwEETvfkWOG1jBtlYUT5JTD0XRY/EQarShaVLTpNSvj4kIy7AzzO5rO25bw1UINR@ZGQauH/BGwj6tEqwzI8QcJJKLn7rzKCx3xoJH0lOKZEPpcfU0lsBtVNKlvKOU/JJKt8pPchZXrl8Caqnl4AeQ8azmy3@P5fQYTq7SD7Ekch8LzHjtErVPgIuV0TE@OXhHH0LT5FhitsNij0X@0zhbjLLBIsMDZvkds/Ie1rP6Ag) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs each entry on its own line with batches double-spaced. Explanation:

```
ＵＭθ…Ｅι⊞Ｏυκ⁰
```

For each element of the input array, push its index `n` times to the predefined empty list, and then replace it with an empty array, thereby creating a master batch list.

```
Ｆ⪪υη
```

Split the list of indices into batches of the given capacity and loop over each batch.

```
Ｆ…·⌊ι⌈ι
```

Loop over each value in the current batch.

```
⊞§θκ№ικ
```

Push the value's frequency to the master batch list.

```
Ｉθ
```

Print the resulting list.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>123</s> <s>80</s> 78 bytes

*Edit: -43 bytes by <s>stealing tricks from</s> blatantly copying [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219382/95126) (please upvote that one!)*

```r
function(s,c)sapply(lapply(split((1:sum(s)-1)%/%c,rep(seq(a=s),s)),rle),`[`,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLbTsMwDH3nKyqhSbF0EHWTXoY0foQHVoWCqpVRlu2Brx@OI6BbK1TLsevjS45zOI@t37Vv3fNLH46b8@tp74/9x94EeArtOA5fZkhHGIf@aAw/hNO7CXTHtLpfeRy60YTu07SbQAhEOAwdYfu0BdNFceONzZHZBhkXpCq7zTaPmZcIFxCpCN5USE4THScH3VyVYZLak9w5orhCgBerFP9X4TiGdYLLL4CI80ZdSwT1PLGctU/fIrKcIMs5wua5jJETGjcBNkKMilOabBXDCxeQ@eGkhVB7dQO9gFWO1YVdoBEluIKszBaqRaQrZI@WsUZkgafza9Eyqibtr5a4ipLmomkTf/qX044TRudgjuZP7l/WxNQm69/Xcf4G)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>93</s> 75  bytes

- Original answer setting the Bounty score required under 93.

```
p,u;f(*l,c,z){for(p=u=0;++u,++p,z;u*=u!=c)--*l&&u-c||printf("%d%c",p,!*l?++l,z--,10:32,p=0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHbbtswDIbv/RRqghZWTCM6@jBD29WeYL0LclG4cRHATYy2BoqkefaMlCynw2BF@Gz@P8mQbd72T4eX63WAsenSVQ8tnPi5O76lgxudaLJshCwb4NSMKzfeuZbn@ap/eBjz9utreNsfPrp0cf983y5ggLtV/yvLejjlOUjxQysYnODN5YoydpSbrTtrAUxXwKS6ABukk6pJ1mv3k202UgGeYgubAgJXyAbvbeITKEogyaecvNliWFPYp9XfwzALzOw3Tv3vtz5MdbUhkXVKkIpNMsAO8SpBCSijqSCTJXkRirJYNTxRV8660tmbzsZ4FYYjsLwgVeUqM7dY4RD8MTQRXSBGXx2axp7BgM9fu@LfrqlpTZMkBo1OFvYh/MDAgiwAd4LrohsP1gJclJZQw7Qo4eS3timlxV/lV1SCtP7QiAyR9sPy36TfYRBQB1ISTbbZcCNKXc97T5bPu25/2LHH338e00/OuvS4XH7CQNf7/rQ7hg98Pb3gP@O8GcaP93TB8tuz4E3iJ/b6tD@wlJ@TkFLyCVQEHcFEsBGKCGWEKkIdQQqk5HL9Cw)

- 75 bytes after some golfing.
- stolen from @Arnaulds the 0 terminated list input.

```c
p,u;f(*l,c){for(p=u=1;*l||*++l;++p)u++%c*--*l||printf("%d%c",p,9+!*l,p=0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLbisIwEH3vV2QVoZcRc21TSvZtv2B9Ex@k2kVwNbgKgvrt7iRpqsvSdDik58wczrSdtrvV/uvxsHBuujTfQZtdu8MxteZsWJPvbre8KHZNUdjsXBSTNp9O3aU9bvenLh1N1pN2BBbq4g211tCsuT/wEzmwxdJcBQUiNBDGgd6BWGYYb5LZzLyTxQIv8ZRLWJQQsEYssS4T34K7FiwoOboZhJEgHKFvLV4JMFDkSw9p@P8eKhBwupCBpgynjkd6IqBTLBVwClWUlU6mgqAMo0mcHZ7IrF6YlVFPpooMHaKiaIIGnjZaDlY1RuKPdPmIEmFU1sE8egcJ/YzalH/dO/PCJeswCNSSsCEa4lPASsAtCe6rdkFgoSAY1DCsjhr2Yt41Vfhqv7QKmPLHhSUdEj42f8f8VgPBeWDMoV42CJ7Ita6HPyEZrzfddr8h84/PeXrJSJcexuMLWCxZY8@nn3REps9nlDWJD@d7td2TNLsmQcmyHvAIRAQyAhVBGUEVgY6gjoBRRMn98Qs)

- `u` is the total counter of pieces.
- `p` is the partial counter.
- `c` is cargo capacity
- when u%c == 0 or current batch (*l) is 0 we print the partial and reset it.

Comment: Doing it one unit at a time is a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 116 bytes

```perl
sub{$c=pop;map[map y///c,/x+|y+|X+|Y+/g],join('',map[X,Y]->[$n++%2]x$_,@_)=~s/(.{$c})(.{1,$c})/$1\L$2/gr=~/x+|y+/gi}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPfc5pAEH73r7g61wKyBY4DJHVIfW@neclDMpcbx1q1tI1QNDNaJf@62T2IEqewHh@73337w6OcV3/iI19kx/XT9z2fZWVRjh6npcIf2/m@PwN/6x527uHOPdy7/lLDryJf2ZYFxLqDe/3xWvGV674P9ZZPYDxxsue1b3soVjv4EEDA5@LhKw/9ZZU9N4L@Mq@Po96iqOweYwpNBsBkCkyEmhaWXTOlRAhoiQaVQINTxBGummlodwoNoqV33eHZDeKCH/6HL0heRhgMXqOgqBo1RBcMu9y4q93cF@G4CcddtwwCzBFoSKMmmmInxiJqSyYI31aEBUEEKJecS6KKJE2BMMg3LUMMIgEcowzNiob6gLOVAq6AuhExkl8vI0qCmEKlZrhDZBij7iNC0szB@ISZfkOg/EIQaredNpwRSV91/zFnb7I/7mxeVD/mFR6PaTmd5Zsd8Pm2dLIxn4xaCuPLYpOpD3xhjy/Zjm5YZZWvNmxd/bOJ7LD53@aFtNo@P7N@8ZuxvnditYFPrD8YDL7d3LKbL@8eVh2Cd9IY9eoefhskum@OPjBz@C1lea3DAiza8SyNYL/@mS82tlM7Xh8l6@ML)

```perl
sub{
  $c=pop;                           #capacity from last input
  map [map y///c,/x+|y+|X+|Y+/g],   #split into same letters case-sensitive
                                    #...and convert into lengths as numbers
  join('',map[X,Y]->[$n++%2]x$_,@_) #stringify order into XXXYYYXX of given sizes
  =~ s/(.{$c})(.{1,$c})/$1\L$2/gr   #lower case every other capacity
  =~ /x+|y+/gi                      #split into same letters case-insensitive
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/),  <s>91 87 86</s>  83 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes by switching to clang and using TABs, as suggested by @AZTECCO*
*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat*

Expects a zero-terminated list of quantities.

```c
m,x;f(int*a,n){for(m=n;*a?printf("%d%c",x=*a>m?m:*a,(m=m-x?:n,*a-=x)?9:13):*++a;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvRCoIwGIXvfYohCNv8B85l5IbtQaKLH2MiuBUWNBBfvbWCwwfn8J1RjAuGKSUP0Tg6hxdHCGxz95X6IRiO9rHm1dGyulVjCXHgePbW6@xlw4todQCOYojM9loqpnldo2FmT/lHPM6BMrIVhPwqXq5kIFsLHcgjqBOo9s@cA2Q0oCT0IFtodpM/jiIQ2TFT7OkzugWnZxLvLw)

Comment: Ah! Zero terminated.. I didn't considered it! Congrats @Arnauld .. You can leave int*x; by using clang instead of gcc

Comment: And -1 by using horizontal tab (9)

Comment: @AZTECCO Thanks! I've also fixed it to support empty lists -- not sure if that's required.

Comment: Nice to help and see a good C solution! For the empty list it's not required, it's guaranteed that lists have at least one batch as x specifications, 87 Bytes should be fine. Btw mine will go down to 87 too using 0 terminated list like yours and tab, and has a different approach! (bounty still yours atm)

Comment: @AZTECCO Ah, ok. I missed that part of the spec. That's -1 byte, then.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
SḶṁẋ@:Œɠ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/44Y5tD3c2PtzV7WB1dNLJBY@a1vw/vFwfSB2d9HDnDCAd@f9/dHS0sYGOsYWOoVEsGCtERxsCWWCGEYwBJKFSQDU6xiZArgGYbwpTAWSYghnGBgZANUBZCxOoDqAGHROQrBnEUB1THUMzkJXGRmASiEx0gATQGYY6lhCHmMbGAgA)

Port of @KevinCruijssen's [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219331/package-distribution/219382#219382).

### Explanation

```
SḶṁẋ@:Œɠ€   Main dyadic link
S           Sum
 Ḷ          Lowered range [0..n-1]
  ṁ         Reshape like
   ẋ@         a list consisting of lists of the second argument repeated each first argument times
     :      Integer divide by the second argument
      Œɠ    Run lengths
        €     of each
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 111 bytes

```clj
#(let[p partition-by](for[k(p last(for[i(partition-all %2(mapcat repeat %1(range)))j(p + i)]j))](map count k)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHbboMwDH3vV1iaKiWaJxHCrZq2H4nyQGmYoAwYTR/29cwOA1phEsfn@Dh2qm5o75ObxcXVUM8vonPejDCWk298M/Rv518r6mEyVzFCV958ODRiJ5RdB8dYfJdjVXqY3OhoOyoxlf2Xk1K2lPgKjbStlJZpUA333sOVsFkexGW4uR8w5gyVBXMwRkegC1CxRfrf4eOTQBXTATOLJsPFL8hPaLWUoYi6MUMkfoygWlnxM0uxkE4oHu0AGi5tcgpiHmjps9jyrUi6ImmI6Cgi0chikaxAQdcMlvCddcbQUp2KY0IK1NhDea6uuTv2US/9YIoqQ12gjsNKRpqoI9QKTximtV2FFUjVFGFKOSHBuLWEPR2aDDEVxrgQuKBS7P2nbQm7x9KnbfRkYpya3nc9iBroCflR/wA)